# Pass variable number of parameters into a function then call a function within my function with those parameters

Tags: python, function, parameters, python-2.x

My apologies if this has been answered - I suspect it's very simple - but I can't see how to do it.

It's easier to demonstrate what I want to do.

```
vflag=True

def printv(*prargs):
    if vflag:
        print prargs
#       print *prargs gives a syntax error, unsurprisingly


printv("hello", "there", "world")
printv("hello", "again")
```

I want the output to be

```
hello there world
hello again
```

and I get (of course)

```
('hello', 'there', 'world')
('hello', 'again')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should do it as:

```
def printv(*prargs):
    if vflag:
        print ' '.join(prargs)

>>> printv("hello", "there", "world")
hello there world
```

The `string.join(iterable)` returns a string of all the elements in the list separated by the specified string, in this case `' '` (a whitespace).

Comment: Well, that was simple - and quick.  Thanks very much indeed.